# How to detect file uploads with OWIN?

Tags: c#, file-upload, owin

I have a simple Owin Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!2 " + context.Request.Path + ".." + context.Request.Headers);
        });

    }
}
```

I can't see how to detect which files are being uploaded when I call it using `curl`:

`curl -F FILE=@C:\test.xls  http://localhost:8437/upload`

I can see (in the Immediate Window in VS) that there is a private property which shows that there is one file (`context.Request.Headers.Store._httpRequest.Files`) but I can't see anything on how to get the file from the request and store in the file system.

I've been able to do this in node so I don't think what I'm trying to do is unreasonable.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Typically, OWIN would be used for middleware; sitting in the pipeline before a web application such as Web Api.  If you do this entirely yourself within OWIN, you would need to handle all of the serialization, headers and response codes yourself.  Is that what you intend?

Comment: Possibly not. I wrote some code to upload files to a remote service (which we cannot access from the CI server). In terms of integration testing I was advised to use OWIN to spin up a server to handle the request my code makes ( the test would upload a file, download it back and then verify the files matched), but I could not find any references to support this use case.

Comment: So you need to upload a file in the request and have the response be that same file in the content, all in one API call?  Or you need to make one call to upload the file, then another file to download the file?  Could you just mock the call within your code with some IoC?

Comment: What I needed to do was the second: "make one call to upload the file, then another file to download the file". As I wasn't getting anywhere I knocked up a quick node server which seemed the quickest way forward. Thanks for your interest @MichaelDotKnox